# Memory profiling on Google Cloud Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

What would be the best way to debug memory issues of a dataflow job?

My job was failing with a GC OOM error, but when I profile it locally I cannot reproduce the exact scenarios and data volumes.

I'm running it now on 'n1-highmem-4' machines, and I don't see the error anymore, but the job is very slow, so obviously using machine with more RAM is not the solution :)

Thanks for any advice,
G

Answer (score 5):

Please use the option `--dumpHeapOnOOM` and `--saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath` (see [docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/java-sdk/JavaDoc/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineDebugOptions.html#getDumpHeapOnOOM)).

This will only help if one of your workers actually OOMs. Additionally you can try running `jmap -dump PID` on the harness process on the worker to obtain a heap dump at runtime if it's not OOMing but if you observe high memory usage nevertheless.