# Job stalls with a log message "Waiting for resources for GetStateData. (...)"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

my job stalls with log messages like this:

```
Waiting for resources for GetStateData.
Memory is used/total/max = 20290/31717/40041 MB,
GC last/max = 71.00/80.00 %, #pushbacks=2, gc thrashing=true 

timestamp   2018-03-14T08:16:36.562Z
logger  com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.MemoryMonitor
```

It looks like a problem with available memory. Can anyone confirm this? Any ideas how to debug this kind of problem?

Comment: [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294249/memory-profiling-on-google-cloud-dataflow) has a good tip for memory profiling and debugging a Dataflow job.

Comment: Memory pressure may not be the root cause. Do you have a job_id for us to look into it?

Comment: @SlavaChernyak Sure, here one of these job_IDs: 2018-03-14_07_42_40-8196846155321555615

Comment: @przemod I checked on the job. It appears to have been operating well until cancelled. While there may have been memory pressure as indicated by the logs above, I did not see it causing any problems. What do you mean when your job stalls? I did not see any indication of this.

Comment: @SlavaChernyak At the beginning, the job was able to process 1000s of events per sec but the cluster was constantly auto-scaling up. After it reached the maximum number of workers, processing rate dropped significantly.

Comment: @przemod, It looked to me like the pipeline was able to pull all of the messages that were backlogged on your pubsub subscription, and after it churned through those it ran out of input. The pipeline conitnued to operate well (continued to have low system lag and advancing watermark) but received no more input from pubsub.

Comment: @SlavaChernyak maybe the job with ID 2018-03-21_06_46_21-18150020711800192363 is a better example.The log is full of messages 
`I  Waiting for resources for GetStateData. Memory is used/total/max = 4328/4945/4949 MB, GC last/max = 99.00/99.00 %, #pushbacks=1, gc thrashing=true`. There were no new messages being pushed into a dataflow, it was stuck for half hour doing nothing and a system lag was constantly growing.

Comment: @prezmod: I recommend you follow up with Google Cloud Platform Support (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support). We don't generally do investigations on particular jobs here on StackOverflow, support is the correct channel.