# Out of memory exception in dataflow with windowing on bounded input

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

I have created a dataflow which takes input from datastore and performs transform to convert it to BigQuery TableRow. I am attaching timestamp with each element in a transform. Then window of one day is applied to the PCollection. The windowed output is written to a partition in BigQuery table using Apache Beam's BigQueryIO.

The job fails with OOM error.

Dataflow Job ID: 2018-03-26_20_45_39-10536011060742036262
workerMachineType used: n1-standard-8

The dataflow pipeline at a high level is:

```java
// Read from datastore
PCollection<Entity> entities =
        pipeline.apply("ReadFromDatastore",
                DatastoreIO.v1().read().withProjectId(options.getProject())
                        .withQuery(query).withNamespace(options.getNamespace()));

// Apply processing to convert it to BigQuery TableRow
PCollection<TableRow> tableRow =
        entities.apply("ConvertToTableRow", ParDo.of(new ProcessEntityFn()));

// Apply timestamp to TableRow element, and then apply windowing of one day on that
PCollection<TableRow> tableRowWindow =
        tableRow.apply("tableAddTimestamp", ParDo.of(new ApplyTimestampFn())).apply(
                "tableApplyWindow",
                Window.<TableRow> into(CalendarWindows.days(1).withTimeZone(
                        DateTimeZone.forID(options.getTimeZone()))));

// Write windowed output to BigQuery partitions
tableRowWindow.apply(
        "WriteTableToBQ",
        BigQueryIO
                .writeTableRows()
                .withSchema(BigqueryHelper.getSchema())
                .to(TableRefPartition.perDay(options.getProject(),
                        options.getBigQueryDataset(), options.getTableName()))
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE));
```

I am getting following error logs several times:

```java
An OutOfMemoryException occurred. Consider specifying higher memory instances in PipelineOptions.
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:182)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner$1.outputWindowedValue(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:104)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:54)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.processElement(BatchGroupAlsoByWindowReshuffleFn.java:37)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:117)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowFnRunner.java:74)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.processElement(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:113)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:187)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:148)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:68)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:330)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:302)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:251)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:135)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:115)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.DataflowBatchWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowBatchWorkerHarness.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:36)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteBundlesToFiles$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory$AssignWindowsParDoFn.processElement(AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.PrepareWrite$1.processElement(PrepareWrite.java:62)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.PrepareWrite$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory$AssignWindowsParDoFn.processElement(AssignWindowsParDoFnFactory.java:116)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:443)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.outputWithTimestamp(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:430)
    at com.ittiam.cvml.dataflow.service.LoadIsmDataflow$ApplyTimestampFn.processElement(LoadIsmDataflow.java:526)
    at com.ittiam.cvml.dataflow.service.LoadIsmDataflow$ApplyTimestampFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at com.ittiam.cvml.dataflow.service.LoadIsmDataflow$ProcessEntityFn.processElement(LoadIsmDataflow.java:478)
    at com.ittiam.cvml.dataflow.service.LoadIsmDataflow$ProcessEntityFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:138)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreV1$Read$ReadFn.processElement(DatastoreV1.java:919)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.datastore.DatastoreV1$Read$ReadFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1.processElement(MapElements.java:122)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.MapElements$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn$1.output(SimpleParDoFn.java:272)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.outputWindowedValue(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:211)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.access$700(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:66)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:436)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner$DoFnProcessContext.output(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:424)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1.processElement(ReshuffleOverrideFactory.java:84)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.ReshuffleOverrideFactory$ReshuffleWithOnlyTrigger$1$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:177)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:141)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:324)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:48)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn$1.output(GroupAlsoByWindowsParDoFn.java:180)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setContentAndHeadersOnCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:603)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:409)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
```

Dataflow pipeline fails with the following error log:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S53:ReadIsmFromDatastore/Reshuffle/Reshuffle/GroupByKey/Read+ReadIsmFromDatastore/Reshuffle/Reshuffle/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow+ReadIsmFromDatastore/Reshuffle/Reshuffle/ExpandIterable+ReadIsmFromDatastore/Reshuffle/Values/Values/Map+ReadIsmFromDatastore/Read+ConvertToTableRow+IsmTableAddTimestamp+TrackerTableAddTimestamp+IsmTableApplyWindow/Window.Assign+TrackerTableApplyWindow/Window.Assign+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/PrepareWrite/ParDo(Anonymous)+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/BatchLoads/rewindowIntoGlobal/Window.Assign+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/BatchLoads/WriteBundlesToFiles+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/BatchLoads/ReifyResults/View.AsIterable/View.CreatePCollectionView/ParDo(ToIsmRecordForGlobalWindow)+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/BatchLoads/GroupByDestination/Reify+WriteTrackerTableToBQ/BatchLoads/GroupByDestination/Write+WriteIsmTableToBQ/PrepareWrite/ParDo(Anonymous)+WriteIsmTableToBQ/BatchLoads/rewindowIntoGlobal/Window.Assign+WriteIsmTableToBQ/BatchLoads/WriteBundlesToFiles+WriteIsmTableToBQ/BatchLoads/ReifyResults/View.AsIterable/View.CreatePCollectionView/ParDo(ToIsmRecordForGlobalWindow)+WriteIsmTableToBQ/BatchLoads/GroupByDestination/Reify+WriteIsmTableToBQ/BatchLoads/GroupByDestination/Write failed., A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service.
```

Comment: [This Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294249/memory-profiling-on-google-cloud-dataflow) has a good tip for memory profiling and debugging a Dataflow job.

Comment: Aside from the advise from the link above, you can obtain heap dumps to analyze from a worker itself, by running:
PROJECT="..."
ZONE="..."
WORKER="..."
gcloud compute scp --project=$PROJECT --zone=$ZONE \
  "$WORKER:/var/log/dataflow/java-streaming/heap_dump*" <SOME_LOCAL_PATH>

Comment: If you find in your logs the ID of the instance where the OOM happens, run the commands above and share the results it might be helpful. In fact, this could be the solution to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49665834/dataflow-abnormality-in-time-to-complete-the-job-and-the-total-cpu-hours-with-re) as well. The OOM might be symptomatic of a hot key (there's a number of GroupByKey transforms in the failing step). A reshuffle could alleviate the load on the failing worker but the issue remains in the later write step, so the pipeline doesn't fail but is now too slow.

Comment: Rewriting the commands for clarity (the 5' edit time window for comments is gone):
    `PROJECT="..."`
   `ZONE="..."`
    `WORKER="..."`
    `gcloud compute scp --project=$PROJECT --zone=$ZONE \
  "$WORKER:/var/log/dataflow/java-streaming/heap_dump*" <SOME_LOCAL_PATH>`