# Dataflow: set DataflowPipelineDebugOptions

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow

My pipeline gives OOM errors constantly so I read a fowllowing answer and try to set `--dumpHeapOnOOM` and `--saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath`. But it seems that these options do not work. Do I need to change my code or modify something else?

[Memory profiling on Google Cloud Dataflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294249/memory-profiling-on-google-cloud-dataflow)

Answer (score 3):

You will want to check [configuring-pipeline-options](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#configuring-pipeline-options).

The current way in Apache Beam (2.9.0) to configure pipeline option in command line is `--<option>=<value>`.

In your case, you can set `--dumpHeapOnOOM=true --saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath="gs://foo"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I set these two parameters and OOM occurred in the pipeline but no file is placed in the bucket. hmm... And I have another question. How do I know Xmx of running dataflow pipeline? Is it even possible?

Comment: the `--saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath="path"` option should be like `--saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath="gs://foo"`. Please tell me if is not correct.

Comment: Yes. I should use more descriptive path name.