# How to debug beam WriteToText running out of memory?

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

The GroupBy during my WriteToText operations fails due to running out of memory which kills my dataflow job. Running the job locally I run out of memory as well.

Based on the WriteToText [source code](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/1d9daf1aca101fa5a194cbbba969886734e08902/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py#L562) it seems to me specifying the number of shards should help with issue. I am not sure how to choose the number of shards though can anyone explain a process to choose the number of shards?

I expect a better sharding approach could mean the pipeline is less efficient but doesn't crash. In general I am not sure how to make dataflow pipelines more robust against failure from large outliers.

For a bit more context y error message on Dataflow looked like this:

```
Workflow failed. Causes: S31:ReadData/Read+BaseNLP+SplitBaseDoc+WriteJSONBaseNLPToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+SplitSentences+NormalisedNESplitSentences+NamedEntitiesSplit+LinkedEntitiesSplit+ExtractMetadata+ExtractSentCoOcc+ExtractDocCoOcc+WriteJSONDocumentToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteDocCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteJSONDocumentToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteNamedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteNormalisedSentenceNEToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteNormalisedSentenceNEToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteNormalisedSentenceNEToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteNormalisedSentenceNEToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteNormalisedSentenceNEToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteJSONDocToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteJSONDocToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteJSONDocToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteJSONDocToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteJSONDocToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteDocCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteSentCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteSentCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteSentCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteSentCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteSentCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteSentenceToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteSentenceToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteSentenceToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteSentenceToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteSentenceToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteMetadataToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteMetadataToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteMetadataToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteMetadataToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteMetadataToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteDocCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteDocCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteDocCoOccToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteLinkedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WriteBundles/WriteBundles+WriteLinkedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteLinkedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteLinkedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteLinkedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteJSONDocumentToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteJSONDocumentToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteJSONDocumentToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteJSONBaseNLPToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteJSONBaseNLPToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteJSONBaseNLPToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteJSONBaseNLPToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write+WriteNamedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/Pair+WriteNamedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/WindowInto(WindowIntoFn)+WriteNamedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Reify+WriteNamedEntitiesToGS/Write/WriteImpl/GroupByKey/Write failed., A work item was attempted 4 times without success. Each time the worker eventually lost contact with the service. The work item was attempted on: 
  datachunk7-03250851-9xfb-harness-jgn7,
  datachunk7-03250851-9xfb-harness-jgn7,
  datachunk7-03250851-9xfb-harness-3hl5,
  datachunk7-03250851-9xfb-harness-g6m5
```

So this shows `WriteNamedEntitiesToGS` is failing which had the following definition:

```
named_entities | 'WriteNamedEntitiesToGS' >> WriteToText(known_args.output, file_name_suffix='_named_ent.json.gz')
```

So this shows the issue is coming from WriteToText which is linked above.

Comment: I think it would likely help if you could post some details of the error.  Maybe the details / stack trace of the execution.  If we were to pare down the pipeline, is there a transform in particular which is throwing the error?

Comment: Fair point @Kolban I added a stacktrace, I didn't have it initially as it doesn't seem super informative to me.

Comment: Do you run any steps after the GBK but before the Write? For example do you create any objects from the List resulting from the GBK?

Comment: @RezaRokni The GroupByKey is called from within the the WriteToText method. So I don't create any objects from the list resulting from the GroupByKey

Comment: This post shows you how to get some more debug information out of an OOMing job. i.e. Memory Profiling.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294249/memory-profiling-on-google-cloud-dataflow

Comment: @AlexAmato thanks for the suggestion will report back with results from running the job with these args

Comment: @AlexAmato interesting rerunning with the commands suggested for OOM debugging  `--dumpHeapOnOOM --saveHeapDumpsToGcsPath` meant the job passed for the first time out of 4 runs. I have another 3 jobs that failed due to the same reason will see if all will run with these args.

Comment: @AlexAmato the next job I tried on still fails and there is no HeapDump in the specified GcsPath though I am not sure if this is due to Python beam lacking the feature or that the issue is not OOM

Comment: My mistake, I suppose the problem here is python beam lacking the feature.

Comment: I think this is the correct way to set the option in python. Please set --profile_location to a GCS path. I think that the defaults for --profile_cpu and --profile_memory are valid.

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a85ea07b719385ec185e4fc5e4cdcc67b3598599/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L625