# Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing

Tags: java, garbage-collection, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am writing Apache beam  BAtch dataflow in which I am writing from GCS to BQ.
My data contains **4 millions of records**. I have specified **n1-HighMem-8** machine type.My dataflow works form small amount of data.

I my use case I schema is not fixed so I have used **.getFailedInserts()** Method to get schema failed records not inserted.

I have grouped them and writing to BQ using BQ load job via GCS in same dataflow.

for this amount of data I am geting following error 7 time and then my dataflow errors out:

E  EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities 
E  Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system

E  Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system 
E  Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /

Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /

[ContainerManager]: Fail to get rootfs information unable to find data for container /

E  PercpuUsage had 0 cpus, but the actual number is 8; ignoring extra CPUs 
E  EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities

E  EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount as ext3 due to feature incompatibilities 
E  Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system

E  Error initializing dynamic plugin prober: Error (re-)creating driver directory: mkdir /usr/libexec/kubernetes: read-only file system 
E  Image garbage collection failed once. Stats initialization may not have completed yet: failed to get imageFs info: unable to find data for container /

Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing. Memory is used/total/max = 27662/33436/33436 MB, GC last/max = 93.00/95.00 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=true. Heap dump not written.

Comment: You may be able to use memory profiling to figure out where you are consuming too much memory and causing the thrashing. Though this may only dump if you actually OOM, which is not the case. I am not sure, its worth a try.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34294249/memory-profiling-on-google-cloud-dataflow

Comment: Do you have any code you would be able to share? And any any stack traces related to the error? It might help debug this.

Comment: BigQueryIO.<Map<String, String>>write().withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
      .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
      .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.neverRetry())
      .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
      // .withExtendedErrorInfo()
      .to(new DynamicDestinations<Map<String, String>, Map<String, String>>() { .......................................

Comment: I have a similar configuration failing with similar error message. Looks like something is failing when Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS is used. The same code worked OK without the statement (and reading from PubSub as opposite to GCS).