# GCP Dataflow running streaming inserts into BigQuery: GC Thrashing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

I am using Apache Beam 2.13.0 with GCP Dataflow runner.

I have a problem with streaming ingest to BigQuery from a batch pipeline:

```java
PCollection<BigQueryInsertError> stageOneErrors =
  destinationTableSelected
    .apply("Write BQ Attempt 1",
      BigQueryIO.<KV<TableDestination, TableRow>>write()
                .withMethod(STREAMING_INSERTS)
                .to(new KVTableDestination())
                .withFormatFunction(new KVTableRow())
                .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.neverRetry())
                .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND))
                .getFailedInsertsWithErr();
```

The error:

```
 Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing. 
 Memory is used/total/max = 15914/18766/18766 MB, 
 GC last/max = 99.17/99.17 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=true. 
 Heap dump not written.
```

Same code working in the streaming mode correctly (if the with explicit method setting omitted).

The code works on reasonably small datasets (less than 2 million records). Fails on 2,5 million plus.

On the surface it appears to be a similar problem to the one described here: [Shutting down JVM after 8 consecutive periods of measured GC thrashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431101/shutting-down-jvm-after-8-consecutive-periods-of-measured-gc-thrashing)

Creating a separate question to add additional details.

Is there anything I could do to fix this? Looks like the issue is within the BigQueryIO component itself - GroupBy key fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive discussions with the support and the developers it has been communicated that using BigQuery streaming ingress from a batch pipeline is discouraged and currently (as of 2.13.0) not supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with transforms that contain GroupByKey is that it will wait until *all* the data for the current window has been received before grouping.

In Streaming mode, this is normally fine as the incoming elements are windowed into separate windows, so the GroupByKey only operates on a small(ish) chunk of data.

In Batch mode, however, the current window is the Global Window, meaning that GroupByKey will wait for the entire input dataset to be read and received before the grouping starts to be performed. If the input dataset is large, then your worker will run out of memory, which explains what you are seeing here.

This brings up the question: Why are you using BigQuery Streaming insert when processing Batch data? Streaming inserts are [relatively expensive](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#streaming_pricing) (compared to bulk which is free!) and [have smaller quota/limits](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaming_inserts) than Bulk import: even if you work around the issues you are seeing, there may be more issues yet to be discovered in Bigquery itself..

Comment: Thank you! The challenge is the inherited code for the inserts - there is a fair amount of error handling and custom logic around it. Can not be reimplemented with the batch loads unfortunately. Is there a way to move away from the global window for batch inserts?

Comment: If you have some time-related thing in the incoming data, you can maybe use that with windowing functions to split the data into windows... But it may still be worth the effort to refactor to use batch...

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, no, nothing specific in the incoming data. But I am OK with setting something up artificially. I tried this, and got some results written. But the pipeline crashed nevertheless. Puzzled.